# Using L298N bridge to control smart lock

Tags: arduino-nano, l298n

I want to use L298N bridge to power up and control simple smart lock. It requires 12V power supply, so I've used L298N bridge to power this smart lock.

I removed jumper from enA pin and connected enA 12V to Arduino Nano D8 pin.

I sent value 255 through this pin but smart lock did nothing. Any suggestions?

I'm using BLE controller to send turn on/off signal from Android App (but its not relevant in this case, because **analogWrite** is called).

Lock:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32949292074.html

Here is code:

```
#define enA 8

void setup() {
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 String msg = bluetooth.read(); //using BLE controller to get message from Android app.

 if(msg == "ON"){
   analogWrite(enA, 255);
 } else if(msg == "OFF"){
   analogWrite(enA, 0);
 }

}
```

Here is setup:

[image]

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds

Comment: Also: you need to control the direction pins or it won't know what to do.

Comment: So I have to ground everything including BLE controller through breadboard like this? https://i.imgur.com/ZueUc82.png (and I'm powering Arduino through USB port)

Comment: that item from aliexpress is not a smart lock ... it is a solenoid

Comment: It looks to me like you failed to tie the grounds of the Arduino and the H-Bridge together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want an L239D to control that lock. It's overkill.  The L239D is a H-bridge that is designed to drive loads in two different polarities (forward / backwards on a motor for example).

That lock is merely a spring-loaded solenoid. You give it power and it pulls the lock back. You remove power and the spring closes it again.

All you need is a simple transistor circuit just like you'd use for a relay.

---

Since you insist on using an L239D, here's a schematic for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFvj2F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I understand that but I dont have time to buy transistor and everything is delayed due to corona. I know that its overkill :D Also I have to apply power to IN1 pin too? IN1 ---- D9 and `digitalWrite(9, HIGH);` ?

Comment: And IN2, which has to be the *opposite* level to IN1. IN1 and IN2 define the direction of current flow through the load. EN1 defines the level of current through the load.

Comment: Ive tried to connect ground pins through breadboard but now L298N is not powered for some reason. Before red LED turn on as I powered adapter. Isnt Arduino powered by USB from laptop a reason?

Comment: Don't forget the L239D's ground needs connecting.

Comment: Ahh so https://i.imgur.com/ZueUc82.png L239D ground can go to minus pins or straight to the top GND pin in Arduino

Comment: Thanks its working. I'm more of a sw guy than hw guy (Android apps) but I had to do this.